# .htaccess for wordpress in separate folder

Tags: htaccess, routing

I'm working on a really odd site which has a couple of Magento installs next to a Wordpress install.

the folder structure looks like this:

```
/shop (magento)
/shop-world (magento)
/wp
.htaccess
```

I just installed Yoast on the Wordpress install and the first thing it did was edit the Wordpress .htaccess settings without creating a backup.

How can I edit this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So that instead of routing all requests through `index.php` (which doesn't exist) the site routes all requests through `wp/index.php`? I tried adding `wp/` on the necessary lines but its not working, and I'm getting an internal server error.

Disclaimer: I didn't make the site like this – but I do need to fix it without moving all the files.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than change .htaccess, move the `index.php` up to root, open it, and change:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

In Settings, your **WordPress address** should be `http://example.com/wp`, and **Site address** should be `http://example.com`.

This process is outlined in the Codex page [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).